# Does a sewn booklet need to be printed differently from a stapled one?

Tags: print-design, booklet, binding

I am making a booklet. I am going to sew the pages together instead of having my printers' staple it.

I am aware that when a booklet is intended for stapling, a calculation is made and the design is shifted slightly once at the printers', to account for the shift that will later on be caused by the binding method.

Does sewing also cause this kind of shift? Does the design need to be shifted at the printers' or not? Should I tell them not to shift the design, or do stapled and sewn binding both cause the same shift?

Answer (score 5):

All books employ **Creep**. Creep is the process of moving each page slightly closer to the outer edge to compensate for the gutter at the binding.

The amount of Creep necessary depends upon the weight of the stock used and number of pages. It's a **mathematic formula** to determine how much the printing should shift from start to center.

I am unclear if you mean you are going to saddle-stitch with thread as opposed to staples, or if you intend to perfect bind with thread. Perfect binding and saddle stitching are configured differently in terns of production. There are **many** possible options. I'd suggest you *speak with a production house* about what you want to do and listen to their recommendations based upon your specific project.

Answer (score 2):

This shift is not caused directly to the binding method, but how your booklet is formed and the type of paper.

By booklet, I do not mean your finished product, but how a sheet of multiple pages is formed and bent, and probably how multiple sheets are put together.

If the amount of pages is the same in each booklet, the shift will be the same because this depends on the paper. But there is a chance the book needs to be formed differently, for example using 2-3 booklets instead of one.

A good method to start understanding this is making a physical booklet as a mockup or dummy with the exact same paper as your finished product will be.

But if you have not a complete control of the printing process and binding, leave that to the printer.

A good tip is to leave a generous margin on the design so you minimize any problem.